# HttpRuntime.Cache Keep Alive

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way to keep the HttpRuntime.Cache items remaining in ram after restarting the application like the stateserver fro sessions?
                    Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. some workarounds are mentioned at [ASP.NET Data Cache - preserve contents after app domain restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766657/asp-net-data-cache-preserve-contents-after-app-domain-restart/1769481#1769481)